# Web Interface to Control Functions in OS

Tags: user-interface, web, interface, operating-system

I'm sure this is a very basic question for most of you but I am curious. I am working on a small assignment and essentially what I want to do is to build a web interface that allows me to control certain functions or configurations in a linux OS. For example, I want a user to be able to login to the web interface and using the web interface, change the configuration for the linux systems hostname. I don't need the actual code etc. to do this, I just want to know where to start. Is it possible for me to get the web interface to call scripts to perform these task? What sort of language is required (besides HTML and CSS)? Whats the best way to go about doing this? Any help is welcome! :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Comment: related to [I never really understood: what is CGI?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2089271/i-never-really-understood-what-is-cgi)

Comment: related to [How do I get started with Node.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353818/how-do-i-get-started-with-node-js)