# How to terminate an EventSource CGI?

Tags: cgi, server-sent-events, openwrt

A bit unsure where to look for this one...

Context:

- HTML5 web page, that uses [HTML5 EventSource / server-side events](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_serversentevents.asp) to get refresh notifications
- OpenWrt BarrierBreaker server, running uHTTPd as the web server
- a two-level CGI script that provides the server-side events:

  1. the CGI is a shell script (ash, not bash), that parses QUERY_STRING, and calls...
  2. a C application that do the true data extraction (from an SQLite database) and pushes the data to the web page

Everything works, except for a little detail: when the web page is closed,
the C application keeps running. Since it doesn't expect any user input, its current structure is a simple while(1). So after some time, the openwrt box has dozens of copies of the app running.

So the question: how can the application be changed to detect that the client isn't there anymore, and that it should quits?

Thanks

[Edit]

Since posting this a few hours ago, i investigated if the information was somehow available in the script's input stream. It appears it isn't.

I also found http://html5doctor.com/server-sent-events/ that describes a strategy to do exactly this in a Node.js environment, but I have no idea how to translate this in a script-based one.

[/Edit]

Comment: In the unlikely case someone else stumbles on this question, I found the following reads interesting about the CGI standard: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2089271/i-never-really-understood-what-is-cgi http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-robinson-www-interface-00

Comment: For now, given that the SSE specification states that the client will reconnect if the server closes the connexion, I used a "middle-ground" approach and decided that the C application will terminates after a specific amount of time. I'm still looking for suggestions, though.