# cgi-bin, bash and formatting output

Tags: bash, apache, cgi-bin

cat /usr/lib/cgi-bin/test00.cgi

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Content-type: text/html"
cat /tmp/file
```

results is:

```
one two three four
```

How format output like a bash script (with newline)?

```
one
two
three
four
```

Comment: Have you tried `text/plain` instead of `text/html`?

Comment: From where is `one two three four` printed? And where is the `echo` string `Content-type: text/html`

Comment: @Inian OP is writing a [CGI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2089271/what-is-common-gateway-interface-cgi) script. So I assume OP refers to the way _a web browser_ is rendering the resulting HTTP response. `Context-type` is part of the HTTP header and as such not directly visible. The rest is apparently the content of `/tmp/file`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you can use both html and UNIX commands

```
#!/bin/bash

echo Content-type: text/html
echo ""

/bin/cat << EOM
<HTML>
<HEAD><TITLE>File Output: /tmp/file </TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY bgcolor="#cccccc" text="#000000">
<HR SIZE=5>
<H1>File Output: /tmp/file </H1>
<HR SIZE=5>
<P>
<SMALL>
<PRE>
EOM

/bin/cat /tmp/file

CAT << EOM
</PRE>
</SMALL>
<P>
</BODY>
</HTML>
EOM
```

Answer (score 0):

Text in HTML is a subject of https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Inline-level_content so all white-spaces (including new lines) are replaced with a single (or more depending on alignment) space.

To alter rendering you enclose text into another HTML elements with assigned rendering model:

```html
<div>line 1</div>
<div>line 2</div>
```

or:

```html
<pre>
line 1
line 2
</pre>
```

Bash has convenient here-document syntax `<<` to code above:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

cat <<EOF
Content-Type: text/html

<pre>
line 1
line 2
</pre>
EOF
```

Alternatively you could use `Content-Type` `text/plain` to preserve original text formatting:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

cat <<EOF
Content-Type: text/plain

line 1
line 2
EOF
```