# How to open git-http-backend as a http server?

Tags: git

[Git official document](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-http-backend) shows the way use git server via http with apache and `git-http-backend`.
I want straight interactive with `git-http-backend` in my program via http.

It's just like what's the apache proxy does but I need control more things from git client, such as refuse client `pull` by his username and the path of repository directory what he request.

how to use `git-http-backend` as a http service straightly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read its documentation at [`docs/git-http-backend`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-http-backend) and see its sources in [`http-backend.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/http-backend.c) ([tested here](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/t/t5561-http-backend.sh)).

Sicne it is a [Common Gateway Interface (CGI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface), it is called by a listener, like an http server, but also *any* other listener(!), like SSH.

See [Gitolite](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/index.html) (an authorization layer), which does precisely that: since it is called `git-xxx` (here: `git-hhtp-backend`), you can call: `git http-backend`: that is what [its gitolite-shell does](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/2cfc81f230a06f629bc977baa66a149adcdbedec/src/gitolite-shell#L140-L141).

Since that backend in turn calls [git services](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/http-backend.c#L629-L639) (git-upload-pack, git-receive-pack, objects/info/packs, ...), you can do what git-http-backend does directly. That is also what [gitolite implements here](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/2cfc81f230a06f629bc977baa66a149adcdbedec/src/gitolite-shell#L216-L234).

Comment: get CGI now.There are a great explanation about CGI at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2089271/what-is-common-gateway-interface-cgi. I decide not struggle it, warping apache http is enough.

Answer (score 1):

`git-http-backend` is described in the documentation as a CGI program. Since a CGI program alone doesn't speak HTTP, you must either talk to it with the CGI protocol instead (this is an inter-process communication protocol involving environment variables and stdin and stdout) or hook it up to an HTTP server such as Apache.

The name might be confusing, but this "HTTP backend" goes *behind* the HTTP server.