# Passing HTML form data to C script and CGI standard behavior

Tags: html, c, cgi

<s>I'm trying to make a login script in C. I want to know, how I can pass the HTML form data to my back-end c script. I'm new to C (coming from perl)</s>

Just do this?

```
<form action="test.c"> or <form action="test.a">
```

How can the script explicitly differ between username and password? Earlier, I just had to do this (in perl):

```
$username = $cgi->param("username");
```

How can I do this now in C. I'm trying to avoid using CGI at all.

Edit 1:

1. It seems I also need to know, how CGI basically works (in short). I'm guessing, the browser is a sort-of compiler for CGI? if not, then is it apache?
2. Since C is not a interpreted language, how does CGI work with C? In perl, I could simply do:

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/perl
   print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
   print "Hello, World.";
   ```

How do I do this in C?

Edit2: Ok, I went over to previously answered questions under the cgi tag here on stackoverflow.

This seems to be the most voted one: [What is Common Gateway Interface (CGI)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2089271/what-is-common-gateway-interface-cgi)

But it still doesn't clear a few things, which I'm asking here.

Since RFC3875 is only a informational doc, and there is no finalized standard.

1. Who implements CGI protocol? Who defines its "standard behavior" on servers such as Apache.
2. How does C files work with CGI in modern environment. Please elaborate using a "Hello World!" as a response to a form submission.

Comment: If you aren't using CGI, how is your code running?

Comment: @SLaks I appreciate the irony, but can you elaborate please? Also, I updated the question.

Comment: CGI means that the web server launches your code (whether interpreted or compiled), passes the request via stdin, and expects a response via stdout.

Comment: @SLaks Who and what describes its "defined behavior" ? Since I'm using apache, is apache's implementation of CGI protocol .. is what I'm using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to help you is a bit difficult.  Your question, in particular the statement "I'm trying to avoid using CGI at all" implies that you're missing a conceptual overview.  In order to 'avoid CGI' you need to replace it with a mechanism to receive, parse and respond to HTTP requests.  That would mean (potentially) writing an HTTP server.  C is a compiled language.  When you wonder if you can do
action="test.c" it shows me that you're missing the fact that  C isn't an interpreted language.

You could use something like [tiny httpd](https://sourceforge.net/projects/tinyhttpd/) to get you started.

This site about [cgi using C](http://jkorpela.fi/forms/cgic.html) will help you.  How CGI is implemented ends up being at the discretion of the implementor.  A hello world program is as simple as the compiled executable of

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
  printf("Content-Type: text/plain;charset=us-ascii\n\n");
  printf("Hello world\n\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: can you please answer the two points I edited in. A theoretical answer would be enough for me, and I will accept your answer to close this question down.

Comment: strange, I can't seem to tag you

Comment: who would be a implementor in this case? Sorry, I didn't understand what you said.

Comment: The implementor is anyone who writes the software.  I'm sorry you don't understand me, but maybe this will make it clear:   I don't know the names of the people that wrote Apache, or the Perl CGI module, or who wrote tiny httpd, but those are the implementors.

Comment: For perl, there is CGI.pm module, it resides on your computer when you install perl (including CGI.pm). That defines the CGI's "standard behavior". 

In my case, I want to know, where is the CGI files actually located. Inside apache ? What is the standard behavior of it?

Comment: I have accepted this answer, even though it does not answer 100% to my query, but still indirectly points at some useful leads. I must say, CGI as implemented by Apache is badly documented. Horribly short is the right expression I think.