# Golang how to deploy a website to hosting

Tags: go

I have bought hosting from [reg.ru](https://reg.ru). I have compiled my website and put it in a subdomain. When I run my app it runs fine without errors. But when I enter that subdomain my website does not respond. I tried adding `.htaccess` file but no success. Is it normal to deploy my `Golang` website to hosting? Or should I buy a server? Can I tell that hosting to serve request of that subdomain from my application?

Comment: What is your hosting control panel? most of the shared hosting doesn't support to  run your own binary,  you need to run your own binary on the system to use golang. it's better to use VPS.

Comment: `cPanel` if you mean that!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Golang is a compiled language. The output of your compiled source code is a binary that could be executed directly on Operating System (that is compiled for) without needing any other software. The compiled binary itself contains a webserver consuming http requests. That's the main difference from interpreted languages like PHP is, where a webserver (Apache, Nginx) is needed to translate incoming requests to a protocol that PHP understands. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2089297/3348617) answer for more information.

> I tried adding .htaccess file but no success

The `.htaccess` file is the Apache webserver configuration file, which you don't need for running a compiled webserver application.

> Is it normal to deploy my Golang website to hosting? Or should I buy a
>   server?

The website hosting providers expect you to run PHP or any other application that understands CGI protocol.

You should proceed similarly as for any other compiled language in order to host your golang webapp: buy a server (VPS) from classic hosting providers or use a public cloud provider.

Another option for you would be to use a managed platform like Google's [App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/) is. It requires you to deploy golang source code and it manages everything else for you. It might save you some devops hassle.

Comment: As I expected. Guess I will buy a VPS server for that

Answer (score 1):

As zdebra mentions in his answer, is is very common for shared hosting plans to support CGI. The [net/http/cgi](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http/cgi) package provides support for this in go. As long as you are using the http server from the standard library, it only requires a minor change to your go program.

`http.ListenAndServe(":8080", myServeMux)` would become `cgi.Serve(myServeMux)`.
`http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)` would become `cgi.Serve(nil)`.

Note that you no longer specify a port, since the port is now configured on the webserver.

There are a few caveats to this:

- This is slower than the built-in http server, since your program has to start up from scratch for every page load. That said, go starts pretty fast. As long as your application doesn't have a bunch of stuff to do at startup, it's not *that* bad.
- You can't run background threads. Your program starts when the request comes in and should die right after the response goes out.
- Memory and go channels can't be shared between different requests.