# How to embed an exe file into webpage?

Tags: server, xampp, exe, ngrok

I have a Windows executable, [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html), and [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/). On the receiving end of my makeshift server, I would like my client(s) to be able to click a link that would open the before mentioned executable on **my** side, and stream the image to my user(s).
I would like if some user input could get through, as arrow keys & space bar, and I'm willing to do this by whatever means possible. Thank you!

Comment: Thank You! I love the support

Answer (score 1):

You could look into [CGI](https://www.oreilly.com/openbook/cgi/ch01_01.html) which provides a way for a webserver to interact with an executable via standard input and output. There is also a [stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2089271/what-is-common-gateway-interface-cgi) detailing what CGI is. For user input, the CGI can pass data both ways, so it should be capable of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: How would I use this to embed, say, [Blender](https://www.blender.org/) onto a client's browser?

Comment: ah this is rather difficult as blender doesn't use standard input not to mention every client would need a separate instance of blender, I do not think what you are trying to do is practical, sorry I can't be of more help

Comment: What about, like a streaming client for me so that it opens on my server, displays it on my computer, and has input through AHK(AutoHotKey) or something?