# On CentOS 8, php-cli is the only option?

Tags: php, apache, yum, centos8

I have a new server with CentOS 8, and I wanna have LAMP on it. In order to integrate PHP with Apache, I can remember there are two solutions: CLI and Apache module. But all howtos that I found are using php-fpm (which apparently is the CLI config with Apache).

I wanna know is there a way to config PHP as an Apache module on CentOS? If so, which package I should install using dnf?

One more thing, I can remember it was recommended to use PHP as an Apache module rather than using it as CLI. Is that still correct?

Answer (score 1):

First thing - `php-cli` is meant for console operation without knowledge of HTTP request, HTTP server env variables and so on. It is used for CLI tasks like scripts run by `CRON`.

What you need is to have [`mod_php`](https://pkgs.org/download/mod_php) package installed. Then you have to enable (and configure) it within apache configuration.

According to [this article](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-php-on-redhat-8) the metapackage `php` should already include `mod_php`, so it should suffice to enable it.

The module can be enabled interactively using `a2enmod` or by adding config directives manually, like:

```
LoadModule php7_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp7.3.so
```

The example is not from Centos, so YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

By `php-cli`, you probably meant [php-cgi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2089271/what-is-common-gateway-interface-cgi).

[php-cli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php) is meant for running scripts from within terminal, not to be invoked from web server.

[mod_php](https://www.php.net/manual/en/security.apache.php) is not threadsafe if used in threaded [MPM](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mpm.html) like `event`.

For best performance you should try [FPM](https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.php), which is separate pool of workers that could be invoked via socket, regardless of actual MPM used by Apache.